# How to store data in windows application

Tags: database, windows

I have worked with databases in my applications but I have only created private use applications so far. Every time I use an access database in my application, I had to install drivers for JET engine on the end user computer. I would like to know more about how to store data on the end user computer without having them to install anything but just the application. It would be great if the data management technique is light and fast.

Comment: You didn't say what language/platform you were developing in, nor what kind of data you wanted to store.  Storing a massive database could use a different method than storing some preferences.  Can you update your question and provide some more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a client-side SQL database then you could take a look at [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/). Databases are just single files, you ship with one tiny library and save all the hassle of installing system-wide components no one else really uses either.

Of course, “data” is a very broad range of meanings so it all depends on what you need and for what purpose. But to replace a JET database SQLite should be very suitable.